Vim embedded terminal prints '\0' as new line
I noticed that printing the '\0' character has no effect if the program that prints it is launched from Terminal, but it "prints" a new line if launched from Vim's embedded terminal. Example code in C:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%c", 0);
    return 0;
}

Can I change this behavior? I would like '\0' not to print anything.
I am using Vim version 9.1.950 installed via Homebrew on macOS Terminal.app.

Welcome to [vi.se]!

The \0 is convsidered as new line in Vim buffers.
The behavior you mention is probably a side effect of this convention.
To my understanding it could be considered as a bug. I would create an issue and wait the feedback od the mainteners.

I submitted this issue.
